# why i am getting Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, web-deployment

can any one please tell me and explain why I am getting this error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" on chrome's console I am building a chat application on NodeJS but I am getting this error can anyone help me please fix this.

client side JS code.

```
Socket.on("message",(message)=>{
    console.log(message)
})

document.querySelector("#message-form").addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const message = e.target.elements.message
    Socket.emit("sendMessage",message)
})
```

html code

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Chatter</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chat.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <form id="message-form" >
        <input name="message" placeholder="Message">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

if anyone need the servers ide JS please comment I will edit the question
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why i am getting Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null javascript

Because when your code runs, there doesn't exists an element with the id `message-form`. The browser haven't parsed that part of the document yet.

Either put your script tag at the end of the body tag.

```html
<body>
  <form id="message-form">
    <input name="message" placeholder="Message">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    document.querySelector("#message-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const message = e.target.elements.message
      console.log(message);
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Or put your js code inside of a [document ready callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/6224823).

```html
<head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      document.querySelector("#message-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const message = e.target.elements.message;
        console.log(message);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="message-form">
    <input name="message" placeholder="Message">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
```